# Python Mysql Update Data only if there are new values

Tags: python, mysql

I catch some data from an url and have around 2400 rows of data in a dataframe.

```
data = pd.DataFrame(dictlist)
df = data.sort_values(["Rank"],ascending=True,inplace=True)


connection = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",    # your host, usually localhost
                 user="crypto",         # your username
                 passwd="abcd",  # your password
                 db="crypto")        # name of the data base

cursor=connection.cursor()
    
sql = "REPLACE INTO coins(Rank,Name,Price) VALUES ( %s,%s,%s)"
    
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    
    cursor.execute(sql,(str(df["Rank"][i]),str(df["Name"][i]),str(df["Price"][i])))#,str(Supply[i]),str(Volume[i]),str(Change24[i]),str(Change7[i]),str(ATH[i]),str(toATH[i])))
    connection.commit()
```

I want to update the values Rank and Price if the Name is already in the Database. I tried REPLACE and also UPDATE ON KEY DUPLICATE but both are not working. It seems that the data append to the old data in the database.

First Run 2400 Values are in DB
Second Run 4800 Values
...

I want only Update existing Values (based on Name) and if they are not in the DB it should be created a new row.

Also it seems that my sort _values command not works. It is still unsorted in the DB

Comment: can you make the name column a primary key?

Comment: shure, is this needed?

Comment: yes so the query can check it a name already exists. try it

Comment: ok i will try, thanks